# Search text in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi I am new to powershell and exploring it.

Requirement : I have multiple with below structure :

```
SAGENT EXPORT FILE
VERSION 18
LOCALE_INFO "1252",".","","-",".".
BEGIN PLAN
  BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
    name=Untitled1
    last_saved_date=2456999,08:38:27.000
    i18n=12
  END ATTRIBUTES
  BEGIN STEP 1
    BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
      name=Subplan
      step_id={40A4A455-4859-4229-BF2D-FB350941CBF7}
      step_type=11
      is_component=0
    END ATTRIBUTES
    BEGIN PROPERTY 1
      BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
        name=AllProperties
        value_type=1
        custom=0
        is_proxy=0
        BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
          [1]=143D7401495BDB81982EFA7BF09092DD6449C6FA21230D16E61D8B7DE1850145531D767D97E2309CD3D2136346472177948123402583722181E3E5732567B4BE348173CA4E3A61F04D69085546C   65-1DEE05E0-BA48-11CF-B2C7-00A02448857E
          [1]=0
        END VECTOR
      END ATTRIBUTES
    END PROPERTY 1
    BEGIN STEP 2
      BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
        name=Time Generation
        step_id={77EDB022-4507-488A-95C0-91C8E22F1F6B}
        display_x=156
        display_y=84
      END ATTRIBUTES
      BEGIN STEPTYPE
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=Time Generation
          clsid={4B343B8B-BCED-11D0-B0B7-00A0C91FDBFC}
          step_type=5
          input_count=1
          output_count=1
          sink=0
          source=1
          dc_step_type=303
          icon_id=0
          visibility=ISD/T
          rt_clsid={fe294e69-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          ct_clsid={fe294e69-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          ui_clsid={fe294e69-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          tip_text=Generates date and time values in the Data Flow
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END STEPTYPE
      BEGIN PROPERTY 1
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=julian_day
          value_type=3
          val_int=0
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 1
      BEGIN PROPERTY 2
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=input_type
          value_type=3
          val_int=0
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 2
      BEGIN PROPERTY 3
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=duration
          value_type=3
          val_int=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 3
      BEGIN PROPERTY 4
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=num_cols
          value_type=3
          val_int=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 4
      BEGIN PROPERTY 5
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=type_0
          value_type=3
          val_int=4
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 5
      BEGIN PROPERTY 6
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=col_0
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=Year
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 6
      BEGIN PROPERTY 7
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=portguid_0
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]={4A5DD351-04A6-4EDB-87C1-071B97771144}
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 7
    END STEP 2
    BEGIN STEP 3
      BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
        name=Expression Calculator
        step_id={691F69C4-5FF6-4DF5-A9C9-FB24EA418AB6}
        display_x=294
        display_y=96
      END ATTRIBUTES
      BEGIN STEPTYPE
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=Expression Calculator
          clsid={4B343BB3-BCED-11D0-B0B7-00A0C91FDBFC}
          step_type=5
          input_count=1
          output_count=1
          sink=0
          source=0
          dc_step_type=303
          icon_id=0
          visibility=IS/G
          rt_clsid={fe294e37-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          ct_clsid={fe294e37-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          ui_clsid={fe294e37-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          tip_text=Uses expressions to add calculated columns
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END STEPTYPE
      BEGIN PROPERTY 1
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ErrorCode
          value_type=3
          val_int=0
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 1
      BEGIN PROPERTY 2
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=USERINIT
          value_type=3
          val_int=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 2
      BEGIN PROPERTY 3
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=FieldOrders
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=-1;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 3
      BEGIN PROPERTY 4
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ExpressionText0
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=ToString (Year )
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 4
      BEGIN PROPERTY 5
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ExprScales
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=0;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 5
      BEGIN PROPERTY 6
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=FieldPassThroughs
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=0;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 6
      BEGIN PROPERTY 7
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ExprIds
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=1;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 7
      BEGIN PROPERTY 8
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ExprEnableds
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=1;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 8
      BEGIN PROPERTY 9
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=UpdateInPlace
          value_type=3
          val_int=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 9
      BEGIN PROPERTY 10
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ExprNames
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=strYear;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 10
      BEGIN PROPERTY 11
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=FieldNames
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=Year;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 11
      BEGIN PROPERTY 12
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=PropAltNames
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 12
      BEGIN PROPERTY 13
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=IncludeNewByDefault
          value_type=3
          val_int=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 13
      BEGIN PROPERTY 14
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ExprLengths
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=0;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 14
      BEGIN PROPERTY 15
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=Version
          value_type=3
          val_int=8
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 15
      BEGIN PROPERTY 16
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=FieldAltNames
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=Year;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 16
      BEGIN PROPERTY 17
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=FieldLengths
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=4;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 17
      BEGIN PROPERTY 18
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ExprCreateNews
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=1;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 18
      BEGIN PROPERTY 19
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ExprOrders
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=0;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 19
      BEGIN PROPERTY 20
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=FieldIds
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=##FIELDID##{77EDB022-4507-488A-95C0-91C8E22F1F6B}0;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 20
      BEGIN PROPERTY 21
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=Copy
          value_type=3
          val_int=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 21
      BEGIN PROPERTY 22
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=FieldDataTypes
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=2;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 22
      BEGIN PROPERTY 23
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ExprExstColumn
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 23
      BEGIN PROPERTY 24
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=PropNames
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 24
      BEGIN PROPERTY 25
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ExpressionNextIDIndex
          value_type=3
          val_int=2
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 25
      BEGIN PROPERTY 26
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ExprPrecisions
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=0;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 26
      BEGIN PROPERTY 27
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=ExprAutoLengths
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=1;
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 27
    END STEP 3
    BEGIN STEP 4
      BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
        name=Rename Columns
        step_id={DA66A76B-3F95-4257-95AE-6BE49957164F}
        display_x=450
        display_y=96
      END ATTRIBUTES
      BEGIN STEPTYPE
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=Rename Columns
          clsid={4B343BAA-BCED-11D0-B0B7-00A0C91FDBFC}
          step_type=5
          input_count=1
          output_count=1
          sink=0
          source=0
          dc_step_type=303
          icon_id=0
          visibility=IS/G
          rt_clsid={fe294e20-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          ct_clsid={fe294e20-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          ui_clsid={fe294e20-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          tip_text=Changes column names
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END STEPTYPE
      BEGIN PROPERTY 1
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=USERINIT
          value_type=3
          val_int=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 1
      BEGIN PROPERTY 2
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=UpdateInPlace
          value_type=3
          val_int=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 2
      BEGIN PROPERTY 3
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=Version
          value_type=3
          val_int=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 3
      BEGIN PROPERTY 4
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=FieldCount
          value_type=3
          val_int=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 4
      BEGIN PROPERTY 5
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=Copy
          value_type=3
          val_int=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 5
    END STEP 4
    BEGIN STEP 5
      BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
        name=Filter
        step_id={D98A52A5-B54D-42E9-8ECC-A905A4135537}
        display_x=576
        display_y=108
      END ATTRIBUTES
      BEGIN STEPTYPE
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=Filter
          clsid={4B343BA1-BCED-11D0-B0B7-00A0C91FDBFC}
          step_type=5
          input_count=1
          output_count=1
          sink=0
          source=0
          dc_step_type=303
          icon_id=0
          visibility=IS/G
          rt_clsid={fe294e0d-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          ct_clsid={fe294e0d-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          ui_clsid={fe294e0d-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          tip_text=Removes rows using filter conditions
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END STEPTYPE
      BEGIN PROPERTY 1
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=MatchCase
          value_type=3
          val_int=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 1
      BEGIN PROPERTY 2
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=TEXTVALUE
          value_type=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=Abc
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 2
      BEGIN PROPERTY 3
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=strOperator
          value_type=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]==
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 3
      BEGIN PROPERTY 4
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=FIELD
          value_type=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=strYear
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 4
      BEGIN PROPERTY 5
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=strValueType
          value_type=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=text
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 5
      BEGIN PROPERTY 6
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=USERINIT
          value_type=3
          val_int=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 6
      BEGIN PROPERTY 7
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=EXPRESSIONS
          value_type=3
          val_int=0
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 7
      BEGIN PROPERTY 8
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=FIELDID
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=##FIELDID##{691F69C4-5FF6-4DF5-A9C9-FB24EA418AB6}1
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 8
      BEGIN PROPERTY 9
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=UpdateInPlace
          value_type=3
          val_int=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 9
      BEGIN PROPERTY 10
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=VALUETYPE
          value_type=3
          val_int=11
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 10
      BEGIN PROPERTY 11
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=Version
          value_type=3
          val_int=3
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 11
      BEGIN PROPERTY 12
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=Copy
          value_type=3
          val_int=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 12
      BEGIN PROPERTY 13
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=FIELDIDVALUE
          value_type=1
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=##FIELDID##{D98A52A5-B54D-42E9-8ECC-A905A4135537}-1
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 13
      BEGIN PROPERTY 14
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=OPERATOR
          value_type=3
          val_int=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 14
    END STEP 5
    BEGIN STEP 6
      BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
        name=Grid
        step_id={63A4BCDA-3C2D-424E-B14D-32BFB67BDFF3}
        display_x=720
        display_y=126
      END ATTRIBUTES
      BEGIN STEPTYPE
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=Grid
          clsid={4B343B81-BCED-11D0-B0B7-00A0C91FDBFC}
          step_type=2
          input_count=1
          output_count=1
          sink=1
          source=0
          dc_step_type=304
          icon_id=0
          visibility=IS/C
          ui_clsid={fe294e93-d35a-11ce-814a-0020afea3965}
          tip_text=Displays results in column format
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END STEPTYPE
      BEGIN PROPERTY 1
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=PresentationColumnInformation
          value_type=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=0   3   BEGIN_COL   113 0   ##FIELDID##{691F69C4-5FF6-4DF5-A9C9-FB24EA418AB6}1  strYear 3       262144  0   0   0   0   0   END_COL 
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 1
      BEGIN PROPERTY 2
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=PresentationParameterInformation
          value_type=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=0   3   0   1   0   4000    1   0   1400    
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 2
      BEGIN PROPERTY 3
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=PresentationColumnHeadingInformation
          value_type=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=0   3   0   404 16498431    1   4   0   52520   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   2   16777215    Arial,8,700,0,0,0   
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 3
      BEGIN PROPERTY 4
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
          name=PresentationRowHeadingInformation
          value_type=1
          custom=0
          is_list=0
          value_attrs=0
          openlink=0
          is_proxy=0
          BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
            [1]=0   3   0   404 16498431    0   0   0   52520   0 0 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0   -167772160  Arial,8,700,0,0,0   
            [1]=0
          END VECTOR
        END ATTRIBUTES
      END PROPERTY 4
    END STEP 6
  END STEP 1
  BEGIN FLOW 1
    BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
      name=Flow
      source_output_no=0
      dest_input_no=0
    END ATTRIBUTES
    SOURCE_STEP=6210134672605708290
    DESTINATION_STEP=6210134672605708291
  END FLOW 6210134672605708289
  BEGIN FLOW 2
    BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
      name=Flow
      source_output_no=0
      dest_input_no=0
    END ATTRIBUTES
    SOURCE_STEP=6210134672605708291
    DESTINATION_STEP=6210134672605708292
  END FLOW 6210134672605708290
  BEGIN FLOW 3
    BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
      name=Flow
      source_output_no=0
      dest_input_no=0
    END ATTRIBUTES
    SOURCE_STEP=6210134672605708292
    DESTINATION_STEP=6210134672605708293
  END FLOW 6210134672605708291
  BEGIN FLOW 4
    BEGIN ATTRIBUTES
      name=Flow
      source_output_no=0
      dest_input_no=0
    END ATTRIBUTES
    SOURCE_STEP=6210134672605708293
    DESTINATION_STEP=6210134672605708294
  END FLOW 6210134672605708292
END PLAN
END
```

Now I need to scan all the files and check which has below section missing in Filter section as there will be both cases i.e below section will be available or will be missing

```
BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
  [1]=Abc
  [1]=0
END VECTOR
```

The above section will always be under Filter Step , however step number may vary

Below is my plan :

1. Search for keyword filter
2. If success find for pattern

   ```
   BEGIN STEP 5
        BEGIN ATTRIBUTE
            name = filter
   ```

   (Note number 5 will vary for different files and I would like to save in temp variable say x)
3. Search for `END step(x)` and save in y
4. Now search for

   `BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos
       [1]=Abc
       [1]=0
    END VECTOR`

   between upper limit and lower limit x and y
5. If found, save the name of file in variable to get the list all such plans which have and which dont have

I am not pretty sure with the approach to follow. Any guidance will be appreciated

Comment: Your plan seems legit, but IMHO the question is too broad for SO. We will not write the code for you, but if you already have some code that doesn't work, please show it and add a problem description.

Comment: I am using below script

Answer (score 4):

When writing parsing code for such formats I have found that in many cases, using `switch -Regex` is a fine approach. You keep state in various variables during parsing and enter different cases based on the regex a line matches.

Something like this:

```
filter Add-Property ($name, $value) {
    $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty $name $value
}

switch -regex ($fileName) {
    '^SAGENT EXPORT FILE$' {
        # file start
        $file = New-Object PSObject
    }
    '^VERSION (\d+)$' {
        $file | Add-Property Version ([int]$Matches[1])
    }
    # ...
    '^BEGIN PLAN$' {
        $plan = New-Object PSObject
        $context = $plan
    }
    '^\s+BEGIN ATTRIBUTES$' {
        $attr = New-Object PSObject
    }
    'name=(.*)' {
        $attr | Add-Property Name ($Matches[1])
    }
    # ...
    '^\s+END ATTRIBUTES$' {
        $context | Add-Property Attributes $attr
    }
    # ...
    '^END PLAN$' {
        $file | Add-Property Plan $plan
    }
}
```

When you have that, you can afterwards look in the structure for what you search. PowerShell's pipelines make this very easy when dealing with objects (which we constructed above). E.g.

```
$matchingFiles = $files |
                 where {
                    $_.Plan.Steps | % { $_.Properties } | % { $_.Attributes } |
                    where { $_ -is [array] }
                 }
```

Or something like that. It depends a bit on how you you parse vectors. You could, for the purposes of this task, of course just add a property to the attributes whether they have a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to parse the file as a multi-line string:

```
[regex]$filter_match = 
@'
(?ms)\s*BEGIN STEP (\d+)\s*
\s*BEGIN ATTRIBUTES\s*
\s*name=Filter\s*
.+?
\s*(END STEP \d+)
'@

$vector_match = 
@'
(?ms)\s*BEGIN VECTOR val_string val_string_pos\s*
\s*\[1\]=Abc\s*
\s*\[1\]=0\s*
\s*END VECTOR\s*
'@

$text = get-content  testfile.txt -raw

$filter_match.Matches($text) | 
foreach {
$x =  $_.groups[1].value
$y = $_.groups[2].value
$HasVector = $_.groups[0].value -match $vector_match

$x
$y
$HasVector

 }


5
END STEP 5
True
```